# How to install build tools on arch with sdkmanager?

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager, arch

If I don't use sudo I get a permission error:

```
$ sdkmanager "build-tools;33.0.1"     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/sdkmanager", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('sdkmanager==0.6.0', 'console_scripts', 'sdkmanager')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sdkmanager.py", line 1141, in main
    method(args.packages)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sdkmanager.py", line 972, in install
    install_dir.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/pathlib.py", line 1175, in mkdir
    self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/android-sdk/build-tools'
```

If I use sudo I get this error (or switch to `sudo zsh)`

```
sdkmanager "build-tools;33.0.1"                                               ✔  root@wiley 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/sdkmanager", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('sdkmanager==0.6.0', 'console_scripts', 'sdkmanager')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sdkmanager.py", line 1141, in main
    method(args.packages)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sdkmanager.py", line 954, in install
    url = packages[key]
KeyError: ('build-tools', '33.0.1')
```

Answer (score 0):

As the output clearly states, `/opt/android-sdk` is not owned by the user, but root. Since you run `sdkmanager` as a normal user, it doesnt get the permission to write in `/opt/android-sdk`.

Running ..

```
cd /opt
sudo chown $USER android-sdk
```

.. will make your user as the owner of the directory and thus grant sdkmanager the permissions to install in that directory.

You shouldn't generally run things like sdmanager as root.